# Create excel file from an object

Tags: c#, .net, excel, c#-4.0

I am looking for a library which would do something like that:

```
Lib.Configure.Cells(...)
Lib.CreateExcelFileFromMyObject<MyObject>(myObject);
```

I believe a long ago I come across such library but cant remember it's name.

May be some one can point me to the right direction.

Comment: Maybe you mean [**EPPLus**](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) where an `ExcelRange` has a `LoadFromCollection<T>` method (besides `LoadFromDataTable`).

Comment: can you please shows us how is <MyObject> declared ? is each property going to be matched to a cell on the same row ?

Comment: @Mauricio Gracia i think the library should be able to give flexibility on what rows i want to include in to file.

Comment: @Sreginogemoh ok, but if you want someone to recommend a specific library they need to know what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I know two ways to read or write excel files.

1. As already said you can access excel files through the `office interop` interface as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/dd264733.aspx). This method is slow, but you can do almost everything what you can do with the gui of excel.
2. Use the [OleDb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms722784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) database interface. This possibility is much faster than the first one, but its restricted to data. So as far as i know it is not possible to read/write formatting e.g. some background color of a cell. With the following function you will get the entire data of a sheet of an excel file at once:

   ```
   private DataSet ConnectAndLoad(string filepath, string sheet)
   {
       DataSet data_set = new DataSet();
       OleDbConnection oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;\"", filepath));
       string query = "Select * From [" + sheet + "$]";
       try
       {
           oledbConn.Open();
           OleDbCommand oledbCmd = new OleDbCommand(query, oledbConn);
           OleDbDataAdapter ole_da = new OleDbDataAdapter(oledbCmd);
           ole_da.Fill(data_set);
       }
       catch (OleDbException ex)
       {
           // do some error catching
       }
       finally
       {
           oledbConn.Close();
       }
       return data_set;
   }
   ```

Answer (score -2):

you can use 
using Microsoft.Office.Interop
namespace to access the ms products

For that first you need to do is add that reference to your project

Comment: This answer provides no specific information about how to achieve that the person is asking

Comment: Go back to your terrible blog until you have got some experience Mr Rafiq.